# Python3 configparser startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar, configparser

I am doing this:

```
tar = tarfile.open("stuff.tar")
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.read_file(tar.extractfile("ook.ini"))
```

The file "ook.ini" is indeed inside the "stuff.tar" archive.

However, I get this:

```
[…] ← Really not relevant stack trace. It's just where my code calls this.
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1030, in _read
    if line.strip().startswith(prefix):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

According to the docs, [`read_file()` read and parse configuration data from f which must be an iterable yielding Unicode strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) so what I am passing it should be fine, shouldn't it?

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 3):

[`TarFile.extractfile(member)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) returns a file opened in *binary* mode. The equivalent for `read_file` is a file opened in *text* mode. As such, the two do not match.

You can wrap your extracted file in a [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) or a generator that converts to unicode:

```
tar = tarfile.open("stuff.tar")
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.read_file(
    line.decode() for line in tar.extractfile("ook.ini")
)
```